# Issue with collapsible pane in Extjs

Tags: extjs

I have developed a screen in extjs which is divided into three sections.The first is the top view then the bottom view is divided into 2sections.The left view and the center view.There is a collapsible pane between the left view and the center view.On integrating this screen with other application I am facing an issue in IE8.What happens is,when I collapse the pane to the left,the top view vanishes away and on expanding the pane also I still do not see it again.Somehow the height of the bottom view increases causing the top view to vanish. Is there any solution for this?Any help is highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: Did you try border layout for this solution ?

Comment: Shouldn't be any problem, I've used border layout in IE8, pls post code.

Comment: yes,i have used border layout.